# Inserting DataTable into Oracle8i Database Table

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable

How do I insert a DataTable contents into Oracle8i Database Table?

1) This is how I did it. I want to know if this is would work:

I made this foreach loop to update the Oracle 8i Database table TABLE using the data from DataTable dt. TABLE and dt has the exact same columns:

Basically, what I did is to fetch the column names of the data table and use that in the insert query and doing the insert row by row:

below is the code:

```
    DataTable dt;
    int intColCtr1 = 1;
    int intColCtr2 = 1;
    strBTConn = strProvider + strUID + strPWD + strDataSource + strPersistSecurityInfo; 
OLEDBconn.Open();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
     strSQL = "insert into TABLE ( ";                      
      foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
      {
       if (intColCtr1<=dt.Columns.Count)
       {
        strSQL = " " + column.ColumnName.ToString() + ", ";
       }
       else
       {
        strSQL = " " + column.ColumnName.ToString() + " ";
        intColCtr1++;
        }
     }
     strSQL = " ) values ";
    foreach (DataColumn column in dtUpdatedLACTM00.Columns)
    {
     if (intColCtr2<=dt.Columns.Count)
     {
      strSQL = " " + column.ToString() + ", ";
      }
    else
    {
     strSQL = " " + column.ToString() + " ";
     intColCtr2++;
     }
    }
                using (OleDbCommand OLEDBcmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLCmd, OLEDBconn))
                {
                    OLEDBcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
    }
```

[edit]: The above code failed because the data in the data table contained oracle and c# escape characters (single quotes and backslashes)

2) Also, if you have better ideas to update the database TABLE using data from DataTable dt, please tell me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what happened when you tried this yourself. Thanks for improving the question for future searchers!

Comment: Why don't you use something like this: 
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT DataTable.* FROM DataTable;

Comment: You use `System.Data.OleDb` classes, would it be possible to switch over to `System.Data.SqlClient` classes? The [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) class was pretty much designed for this exact situation. If you can't switch you might get better performance from [`OleDbDataAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I forgot to mention that the database I'm using is Oracle8i. Would this class work on Oracle 8i?

Comment: No, SqlBulkCopy only works with servers that you can use `SqlConnection` on. You can not use `SqlConnection` on Oracle8i (I think. If you can, it might work)